# Why I got an error at "node-gyp rebuild" at Win10?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I got a problem when running `node-gyp rebuild`. Run it as administrator has the same problem. Please help me to fix it.

## My configuration

- Windows 10
- Node.js `14.15.0`
- Python `3.10.7`
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 is installed
- Git Bash

## Console output

```
$ node-gyp rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.2.0
gyp info using node@14.15.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.7 found at "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.28307.2094) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v14.15.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\dev\\web-chat-core\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v14.15.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.15.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.15.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v14.15.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\User\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\14.15.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\dev\\web-chat-core',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'D:\\dev\\web-chat-core\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
gyp info spawn args ]
Выполняется последовательная сборка проектов в этом решении. Чтобы включить параллельную сборку, добавьте параметр "/m".
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018: непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи AssignTargetPath". [D:\dev\web-chat-core\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018: System.NotSupportedException: Данный формат пути не поддерживается. [D:\dev\web-chat-core\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    в System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath) [D:\dev\web-chat-core\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    в System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath) [D:\dev\web-chat-core\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssignTargetPath.Execute() [D:\dev\web-chat-core\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [D:\dev\web-chat-core\build\binding.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2850,5): error MSB4018:    в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() [D:\dev\web-chat-core\build\binding.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.0\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:203:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\dev\web-chat-core
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was at combination of

- Microsoft Visual Studio
- Node.js
- `node-gyp`

I bring it to work with

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (C++ desktop build tools)
- Node.js `16.18.0`
- `node-gyp` (latest version for october 2022)